# if statement in nginx conf location directive throws error while evaluating environment variable

Tags: docker, nginx

I am trying to put an if block in the location directive of Nginx Conf file. I have already read the **If is evil** document and followed the guideline to put return with the scope of if block.

```
location ^~ /foo/bar/ {
        if ( $ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE = '' ) { 
           return 404;
        }
        proxy_pass $ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE;
    }
```

The if statement above compares an environment variable passed through the docker run command given below.

```
docker run --rm -p 8081:80 -e ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE=https://example.com/ nginx-image
```

Expected Outcome:
That if the environment variable is not passes/set then - accessing /foo/bar will throw 404.
And if environment variable is passed/set then - proxy_pass will work.

Actual Outcome:
[emerg] 1#1: invalid condition https://example.com/ in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:25

Can someone please help? Can't figure out why this is throwing error.
Have already tried the following but got the same error.

```
if ( $ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE = "" ) 
if ( $ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE ~ "^$" )
```

Comment: not so strong in nginx configuration but IIRC the `if` can be used only with internal variables. The environment variables are exploded in the nginx configuration. I'm not 100% positive since the documentation is not very clear: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#if

Answer (score 0):

Environment variable evaluation doesn't work in nginx conf file.I have tried a different approach and split the conf file into two files and load the file which is needed depending on the environment variable. The environment variable is evaluated in docker startup script.